# Windows 10 - Connect to Wifi with Password

Tags: wifi, command-prompt, netsh

I am trying to connect to secured Wifi via the command prompt. The profile is added as I can see it with the `netsh wlan show profile` command. The problem is that I can run `netsh wlan connect ssid="MYSSID" name="PROFILENAME"` and get a response `Connection request was completed successfully.`, however, when I check the Wifi profiles, the computer asks for a network key. Any search (for me) results in adding profiles with passwords, not connecting to said profiles. Is there a way to bypass manually entering in the Wifi password when connecting?

.xml file (created by using `netsh wlan export profile`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>ssid_name</name>
<SSIDConfig>
    <SSID>
        <hex>some_hex_string</hex>
        <name>ssid_name</name>
    </SSID>
    <nonBroadcast>true</nonBroadcast>
</SSIDConfig>
<connectionType>connection_type</connectionType>
<connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
<MSM>
    <security>
        <authEncryption>
            <authentication>auth_type</authentication>
            <encryption>encryp_type</encryption>
            <useOneX>false</useOneX>
        </authEncryption>
        <sharedKey>
            <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
            <protected>true</protected>
            <keyMaterial>really_long_hex_string</keyMaterial>
        </sharedKey>
    </security>
</MSM>
```

Comment: Yes. create profile that contains the password.

Comment: I did create a profile using an .xml file that contained the password. However, when I use the script to connect and I open the Wifi shortcut, it still asks for a network key. I created the .xml file using the `netsh wlan export key=clear folder = "FOLDER PATH"` command

Comment: would be great to see the XML

Comment: Added XML to the question

Comment: The profile looks correct. However I see you have protecte dflag set to true. That requires to use WLAN encryption functions to provide correct keyMaterial value. Try to set protected to false, add pasphrase as it is and add this profile (Windows hides it when you add the profile so passphrase can not be cracked). This should work.

Comment: I switched the protected flag to false but now I'm getting "Profile format error 0x40004:Invalid PSK length" error

Comment: can you show your profile with all fields set except passPhrase?

Comment: I believe it might have something to do with the actual network settings. If I initially connect by manually entering the password then delete the profile, I can then add the profile back and it connects automatically without putting the password in again. I'm guessing it has something to do with cache and the initial connection to the network.

Comment: Probably but I have never seen such issue. Usually something wrong in profile.

Answer (score 0):

the value in `<keyMaterial>` most be generated in the same machine with the same user, you cannot use it if encoded. The other option is to set `<protected>false</protected>` and the password in clear text in `<keyMaterial>Your_password_incleartext</keyMaterial>`